# Applying Kaiser Window to sinc interpolation

Tags: interpolation, window-functions, sinc

I am trying to apply the kaiser window during sinc interpolation.

The following is my sinc interpolation code:

```
def sincTrain(sig, interpolationFactor):
    tn = np.arange(0,len(sig),1)
    t  = np.arange(0,len(sig),1/interpolationFactor)
    
    sincTrain = np.zeros((len(t),len(sig)))
    
    w = np.kaiser(len(t),2.5)
    nind = 0
    for n in tn:
        sincTrain[:, nind] = sig[nind]*np.sinc((t - n)) * w
        nind+=1

    return np.sum(sincTrain,1)
```

I realised that the kaiser window does not follow my sinc function. I have added the plots below to better illustrate the problem I am having.

[image]

[image]

How can I modify the code such that the kaiser window moves along with the sinc function?

Comment: you want to center the sinc function and the Kaiser window together.  that's now how you are displaying it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `t-n` as the argument for `sinc()`, in order for it to be calculated at different points in time, but you are generating the window based on a fixed `t`. Try applying `t-n` there, as well. Also, don't forget that the widow looks to be shifted, while your `sinc` starts at 0.

Comment: I understand the issue now. Could you also explain how the kaiser window can be converted to change with t-n ? The in-built numpy package only allows for a kaiser window to be generated based on a fixed t.

Comment: If it doesn't allow shifting then you may need to implement the function, yourself. [This](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/37714/17189) might help.

Comment: okay thank you, I will try implementing the function myself